# boost asio client authentication

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, network-security

I have a client server based c++ application which communicates over network (with boost asio) and I am planning to distribute this client application to my customers. My problem is I don't know how to prevent connection request from other applications, that  is how can I make sure that only my client application is able to connect to my server. I think there is no way to do this without making the connection, than what is the best way to verify that request is coming from my client?

Comment: I had the same problem; my solution to this was to use a SSH tunnel. You have to open the tunnel beforehand, but you directly rely on an existing mechanism to address this concern.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **asio**'s builtin **SSL** ability. So, you generating sertificates for each server, and client sertificates. So you can check client sertificate on server at the moment of SSL handshake. As a bonus, your traffic will be encrypted and SSL-secure. Clients can check server is not a fake; server can check clients are authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to accept the connection in order to know if it's from your application or not.
You can use a three-way handshake at the connection step:

1. Client connects to the server The server is sending an specific
   value (integer, strings or whatever) to the new client.
2. The client handles this value, compute a new one with it and sends
   the new value to the server.
3. The server checks if the returned value is correct or not.

The client will have the same compute method as the server. The others applications will not be able to use your service if they returned a bad value.

Comment: This is vulnerable to replay attack.

Comment: It doesn't. The replay attack is not a problem if you implement the handshake correctly ...